# extract pyc from Application bundle

Tags: python, macos, py2app

Is there anyway the pyc file can be extracted from an Application bundle? I'm referring to an application bundle that was created by using py2app on python code.

Answer (score 1):

The pyc files are stored in a zipfile in the Resources folder. The name of the zip file depends on the Python version, for 2.7 it is .app/Contents/Resources/python2.7/site-packages.zip.

That zip file is a regular zipfile that can be manipulated with the usual tools.